# Morphia aggregation stage group with object push

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I'm using that latest version of morphia (1.3.2) and I'm trying to replicate the following succesfull mongodb aggregation stage in Java:

```
{
  _id: null,
  pv: { $push: { t: '$_id', c: '$c' }}
}
```

example input to stage is:

```
{ 
    "_id" : NumberLong(1487808017), 
    "c" : NumberInt(1)
}
{ 
    "_id" : NumberLong(1487808210), 
    "c" : NumberInt(1)
}
{ 
    "_id" : NumberLong(1487808914), 
    "c" : NumberInt(1)
}
```

and the expected output is:

```
{ 
    "_id" : null, 
    "pv" : [
        {
            "t" : NumberLong(1487808017), 
            "c" : NumberInt(1)
        }, 
        {
            "t" : NumberLong(1487808210), 
            "c" : NumberInt(1)
        }, 
        {
            "t" : NumberLong(1487808914), 
            "c" : NumberInt(1)
        }
}
```

The closest I have managed to get so far is:

```
.group(Group.grouping("pv", Accumulator.accumulator("$push", (Object) "{t: '$_id', c: '$c'}")))
```

but morphia is interpreting my accumulator as an explicit string.

If anyone could advise on the correct Java syntax to achieve this operation that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Gah, after hours of searching, I worked out the answer within a few minutes of the OP:

```
.group(Group.grouping("pv", Group.grouping("$push", Projection.projection("t", "_id"), Projection.projection("c", "c"))))
```

I came across the possible solution while browsing the morphia tests [here](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/commit/28a57635f06dcc5c2c606dd8621cda918127ec5f).